# Where are the C header files in Windows?

Tags: c, windows

I'm new to Windows development, having messed around in Linux for a while. I need to access console functions and am having trouble getting a comprehensive list of console text attributes off the web. I would like to read wincon.h and windows.h to get the info, but I can't figure out how to get at them. Help please!

Comment: Which compiler?  The header files are in different locations based on the compiler that you are using.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682088(VS.85).aspx - although the header might well list the #defines, searching MSDN for the description of Windows functions is usually better.

Comment: I actually need these for a python program which interfaces with the windows API console functions. I do have Visual C++ Express, however.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Windows does not come with these by default. If you are looking for them, you need to install the Windows SDK and dig around in the %PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows directory.

Comment: For Windows 10 build 17763 SDK, if installed via Visual Studio Installer, the location is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\`.

Answer (score 13):

They're normally stored along with the other SDK headers. Assuming you're using Visual Studio, the easy to look at them is to create a file, add a line to `#include` the file you care about, right click it, and click on the `open document <whatever.h>` line in the pop-up menu.

Comment: Beautiful, no digging around whatsoever

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to install the Windows SDK to get the header files. Windows doesn't come with the software development tools out of the box and depending on which compiler you're using, they might not come with the compiler either.

Answer (score 0):

I would try looking up the console function listing on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Already did. As I said, it's not comprehensive, and I'd like a full list, including  the actual values for the constants defined in the header file: I need the values for some python console programs.

Comment: Had a look at the documentation on the CHAR_INFO structure on MSDN? Containers a listing of the names and values of the character attributes.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, but again, not comprehensive
FOREGROUND_BLACK     = 0x0000
FOREGROUND_BLUE      = 0x0001
FOREGROUND_GREEN     = 0x0002
FOREGROUND_CYAN      = 0x0003
FOREGROUND_RED       = 0x0004
FOREGROUND_MAGENTA   = 0x0005
FOREGROUND_YELLOW    = 0x0006
FOREGROUND_GREY      = 0x0007
FOREGROUND_INTENSITY = 0x0008
These are some more that I found elsewhere. I am curious as to whether there are any more special values.

Comment: I could write a script to loop through all the possible hex values and check, but that would be very tedious to read.

Comment: Well, just looking at those values, wouldn't it seem logical that the "special" values are simple the RGB combinations of the 3 base colors red, green and blue, and an intensity bit for the most significant bit? If you interpret the description in the CHAR_INFO the right way, that's what "Text color contains 'color'" means? Upvoted the approved answer though, because it's for your actual question.

Comment: COMMON_LVB_LEADING_BYTE
0x0100

 

Leading byte.

COMMON_LVB_TRAILING_BYTE
0x0200

 

Trailing byte.

COMMON_LVB_GRID_HORIZONTAL
0x0400

 

Top horizontal

COMMON_LVB_GRID_LVERTICAL
0x0800

 

Left vertical.

COMMON_LVB_GRID_RVERTICAL
0x1000

 

Right vertical.

COMMON_LVB_REVERSE_VIDEO
0x4000

 

Reverse foreground and background attribute.

COMMON_LVB_UNDERSCORE
0x8000

 

Underscore.
I mean values like these

Comment: But thank for the info about the colors. I didn't realize that - I'm still and amateur. Now they'll be easier to remember.

Comment: That's a good question, their documentation isn't exactly fulfilling regarding what actions they perform.