# Where to find missing "C" include files. (*.h)

Tags: c, include

I extracted a program from a [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2146548/2079103) and tried to compile it, using the MSVC++ V6 IDE, but the compiler complained that I don't have any of the following .h include files:

```
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <arpa/inet.h>
 #include <net/if.h>
 #include <ifaddrs.h>
 #include <errno.h>
```

How do get these missing include files?

Comment: Most probably, because of not using `gcc` to run your program. I'm not a fan of MSVC and Windows based development, but you can compile the program by installing `Mingw-w64` on Windows using this [link](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download).

Comment: duplicate of: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119915/where-are-the-c-header-files-in-windows>

Answer (score 2):

The header files which you mentioned above are related to linux based distribution. These are used for socket programming on linux. You can easily run this code on a linux based distro.

Answer (score 0):

The missing header files are unix/linux headers.

The Windows socket API is slightly different from the Berkely socket API (sockets in Linux). In Windows, most declarations needed are available through a single include file, either the old `winsock.h` or the newer `winsock2.h`.

You will need to do some further modifications to port your code. There are good guides on [porting socket applications to Winsock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: When I put together a "C"/CPP program, I will usually put in a standard set of 
      default includes.  Such as:  

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <io.h>

And maybe following:
   #include <winbase.h>
    #include <winuser.h> 
    #include <windows.h>