# Adding basic #include commands to VS Code

Tags: c++, include

I am currently working on a game and decided to download VS Code. However, VS Code is not familiar with basic `#include` concepts such as `#include <iostream>`. I have no idea how to add it because I'm not used to VS Code and the only other programming software I used was at a skills center which already had `#include` commands saved. What do I do?

Current code:

```
    {
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "/usr/include",
            "/usr/local/include",
            "${workspaceRoot}",
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "/usr/include",
            "/usr/local/include",
            "${workspaceRoot}"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceRoot}"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE"
        ],
        "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    }
],
"version": 2
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "familiar with basic #include concepts such as #include"? What are your symptoms?  Do you have any C++ code that you failed to compile? How is the configuration file you posted relevant?

Comment: What language is that?  It doesn't look like C++ to me.

Answer (score 0):

From the file you posted, I assume you have the `ms-vscode.cpptools` extension installed. The issue is not with VSCode "not being familiar with `#include`", it's with your configuration of where it should look for header files.

You need to add paths to the C++ standard library headers (and any other library's headers that you want to use) to the `"includePath"` array for the platform you're using in the file you posted, before the IDE will provide parse support for them.

For Linux this is normally around `/usr/include`, which is already set, so I assume you're using Windows. You'll have to look around for them, but they'll likely be in the Windows SDK installation directory (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119915/where-are-the-c-header-files-in-windows) for a discussion on the Windows SDK), or somewhere like: `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/include`. It'll depend on where your installation of the headers are.